# Best practices for nested QStandardItemModel with children requiring different headers

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, pyside2

I'm wondering about your thoughts on best practices with regard to a QStandardItemModel who's top level items may contain children best represented in another view - and who's horizontal header labels may need to be completely different than the children.

Let's take an example where we have QTreeViewA and QTreeViewB.

*Just to be clear, this is not a literal example. In my actual program, the number of top level items in QTreeViewA would never likely exceed 10, and the children in QTreeViewB would typically be less than 50. The data represented is loaded and saved via JSON.*

In QTreeViewA we want to list pet owners and some demographic info, but when we expand the items we want to see a list of their pets :

```
Pet Owner Name | Age              | Gender | Location
-----------------------------------------------------------------
[+] Rich       | 18               | M      | Los Angeles, CA    
[-] Jane       | 25               | F      | San Francisco, CA
     Dog       |   Border Collie
     Dog       |   Golden Retriever
[-] Jim        | 83               | M      | London, UK
     Cat       |   Calico
```

In QTreeViewB, we want to populate the items of the view when the Pet Owner in QTreeViewA is selected and show some additional information.

QTreeViewB would look like:

```
Pet Type | Breed            | Fur Color     | Age  | Eye Color
------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dog  | Border Collie    | Black & White | 5    | Blue
    Dog  | Golden Retriever | Golden        | 7    | Brown
```

I'm having a bit of trouble setting on the best practice for structuring the model(s).

If I were to just use the same model, and make the QStandardItems for pets the children of the QStandardItems for owners - I'm having trouble finding information about how I could change the Horizontal Header Labels of QTreeViewB to be different than those of QTreeViewA since they're the same model.

Which leads me to ask the question, **is this generally the wrong way to do this?** How would you recommend someone structure a non-conforming hierarchical model like this? Am I overcomplicating the model, should I have multiple models?

I should add, however, in my particular case - I don't actually NEED to represent anything other than the first column in treeViewA. In my real example - when the "Pet Owner" item is selected, QTreeViewB is populated, but so are several other QLineEdit/QComboBox/QSpinBox widgets that are linked to the items in the "Pet Owner" row with a QDataWidgetMapper.

How would you go about this?

Comment: Please have in mind, that opinion based questions are considered off-topic on Stack Overflow. In order to increase the chance to get help from the people around here, I would suggest you to rework your question to focus on one particullar problem and to share an attempt to solve the problem in the form of a minimal and verifiable code example.

Comment: Thanks, probably the better way to ask the question (or what I should have asked first) would be:

I have a QStandardItemModel that needs different horizontal header labels in different views.

Is it possible to decouple the header of a QTreeView from the model in that way?

If the answer to that is no - I probably need some pointers on what I'm doing wrong with the way I'm structuring my models.

Comment: Yep, that sounds more appropriate.